# How to make a modal fullscreen?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to make a bootstrap vue modal fullscreen. Which css classes should I override, I want to do this in a scoped style in the component that will use this modal.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried overriding the classes by using emmanuels answer https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1730, I have tried globally overriding the modal-body, modal-content, modal-dialog class and giving them 100% width and height (the height worked but the width wasn't working and I couldn't figure out why)

Comment: The width needs to be overridden using `max-width: 100%`. There is an additional media query that has the dialog set to 500px.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to edit `.modal-dialog` and force the dimensions.

Example CSS:

```
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}
```

Additionally to get this working in vue. You can try adding a class to b-modal and trying something like this:

```
<div>
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-button>

  <!-- Modal Component -->
  <b-modal class="test-modal" id="modal1" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test-modal .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: This works globally but I only want to change this modal, how can I access .modal-dialog if i assign a class to b-modal?

Comment: Just to mention if anyone else will face same issue. Currently u need to assign class via "modal-class" attribute on b-modal not "class".

Comment: Nice, but is there a way to add a scroll bar on both the X and Y-axis for the contents? Because as of now if there is more data then they are not visible at all.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 You can take a look at the overflow property for css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow There are examples for x and y axis

Comment: And you may also need add `/deep/` for stylesheet.At least, this work for me now.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on the accepted answer, to apply this locally by applying a class to the outer modal div, you need to use the the `modal-class` property on the component rather than giving it a class like you would normally.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#variants

JS:

```js
<b-modal modal-class="modal-fullscreen">
    ...
</b-modal>
```

CSS:

```css
.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but is there a way to add a scroll bar on both the X and Y-axis for the contents? Because as of now if there is more data then they are not visible at all.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Did you mean ["scrollable"](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#scrolling-long-content)?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to alter the CSS, you can just add `.modal-xl` next to `.modal-dialog`.

For example:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
```